Transient NREs when loading many-to-many related entities meanwhile they are inserted
I have three tables: A, B, AtoB. A and B relate as may-to-many via the AtoB:
public class A
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<B> Bs {get;set;}
    public List<AtoB> AtoBs {get;set;}
}
public class B
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<A> As {get;set;}
    public List<AtoB> AtoBs {get;set;}
}
public class AtoB
{
    public int AId {get;set;}
    public int BId {get;set;}
    public A Aa {get;set;}
    public B Bb {get;set;}
}

My DbContext:
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As {get;set;}
    public DbSet<B> Bs {get;set;}
    public DbSet<AtoB> AtoBs {get;set;}
}

in EF I have such a configuration for A:

        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<A> builder)
        {
            builder.HasMany(x => x.Bs)
                .WithMany(x => x.As)
                .UsingEntity<AtoB>(
                    x => x.HasOne(x => x.B)
                        .WithMany(x => x.AtoBs)
                        .HasForeignKey(x => x.BId)
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict),
                    x => x.HasOne(x => x.A)
                        .WithMany(x => x.AtoBs)
                        .HasForeignKey(x => x.AId)
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                );
        }

Sometimes I load data in the following way:
var as = await _dbContext.As
    .Include(x => x.Bs)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.AtoBs)
    .ToListAsync();

Next, when entities are loaded and the list is not empty, I get NRE exception 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object', when performing such a query and accessing BId property:
var filteredAs = as.Select(a => new { projected = a.AtoBs.FirstOrDefault().BId }).ToList();

Why does this happen? It seems like it occurs in the same time when entities are inserted to the tables. But if AtoB row is not yet inserted, then no Bs should be in the A...

Please edit your post and include the exception text.

It is obvious, a.AtoBs.FirstOrDefault().BId may throw NRE. So assumption that inner list is not empty is wrong.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv but how this could be? B and AtoBs are inserted via the single SaveChanges call. So I expect that either both tables have new rows and inner list is not empty, or both rows are not insterted

My crystal ball is broken. Replace FirstOrDefault() with First() and ensure that exception type is changed.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv yes, it changes, but I tried [0].

Try _dbContext.As.AsNoTracking()... maybe ChangeTracker has bad data.

I checked my code, AsNoTracking is used. Could it be related to SQL Server 12? Or it is 100% that two rows are inserted in different tables absolutely atomically.

I don't know check executed SQL. Something with data.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv i guess i found possible reason, but have to check... I did not mention this in the original question, but the query includes AsSplitQuery, that's why it could happen.
